# Referencing a cell with Web.Contents in Power Query in Excel 2013

Tags: reference, powerquery

I have the following query which gets historical data from coinmarketcap for a particular coin, in this case EOS.

```
let
    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(**"https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/eos/historical-data/?start=20130428&end=20180309"**)),
    Data0 = Source{0}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data0,{{"Date", type date}, {"Open", type number}, {"High", type number}, {"Low", type number}, {"Close", type number}, {"Volume", type number}, {"Market Cap", type number}}),
    #"Sorted rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed type",{{"Date", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted rows"
```

I used CONCATENATE to create a link which uses the today date(same format) as the end date so it updates every day. How do I reference the cell which contains the link in Web.Contents? I haven't used Power Query before and I would appreciate it if someone could walk me through the steps. I am really frustrated that such a simple and certainly very used operation doesn't have a ready made solution. Referencing a static web link is straightforward but absolutely useless.

Thanks very much in advance for any responses.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to a cell in an Excel sheet, using syntax like:

```
Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=MyRangeName]}[Content]{0}[Column1]
```

That will lookup the value in table/named range: MyRangeName, at the 1st row, 1st column.

Pass that expression as the 1st parameter for Web.Contents.

When EOS takes off, you owe me a lambo ...